# mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars) function not working when editing values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Italy language as main language in my website so when i edit details the some of language characters automatically converting to special character. does anyone know how to fix this issue...!

here is the code which i used to edit database value and convert specialchars

```
$title7      = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['title7']));
$description7    = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['description7']));
```

Here is the full code which i used to edit database values

```
// connect to the database
 include('db.php');

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
 if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
 {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $language       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtLanguage']);
 $pkg_name       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pkg_name']); 
 $category       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
 $title          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
 $description1   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description1']);
 $title2         = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title2']);
 $description2   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description2']);

 if ($pkg_name == '' || $category == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in Package name field!';

 //error, display form
 renderForm($id,$language,$pkg_name,$category,$title,$description1,$title2,$description2);
 }
 else
 {   

 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("UPDATE saved_packages SET 
 language       ='$language',
 pkg_name       ='$pkg_name', 
 category       ='$category', 
 title          ='$title',
 description1   ='$description1', 
 title2         ='$title2', 
 description2   ='$description2', 
 WHERE id='$id'"); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: adm_view_package.php"); 
 }
 }
 else
 {
 // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
 echo 'Error!';
 }
```

And here is the result
[image]

Comment: Where's the code that actually handles the database persistence?

Comment: @Jack i have added the database persistence code

Comment: I would venture a guess by saying that the database session character set is wrong (i.e. latin1 or iso-8859-5); otherwise the page encoding is wrong.

Comment: im using this as database session character set (utf8_unicode_ci)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `htmlspecialchars` when save data to database.

You should only do:

```
$title7      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title7']);
$description7    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description7']);
```

And when render the data get from database, use it:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($title7);
echo htmlspecialchars($description7);
```

Comment: I have tried this method but still not working for my editing part

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> this is what im using

Comment: @root `<meta>` headers aren't going to help if the response headers are wrong, i.e. `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` is what you should have.

Comment: @Jack can you tell me to where i should have this code?